# VBA, 'Left' Different Strings Dynamically

Tags: vba, excel

Having trouble shortening strings in a column but making it dynamic for a directory. Ex: 3 strings in a column, 1 string may continue for 10 rows, another string 20 rows, and another for 15 rows. Each needing to be shorted a different amount

Specifically: I had several words that are either sepearated by a -, _ , +. So example one sheet has pv01_52352, pv+50, pv-100, irvega_242422, so the irvega word works. but for the pv's i am struggling with. The desired results are the works before the special characters, so it would be pv01, pv and irvega as a desired result .

How can I use left or anyway to shorten these all? It is quite hard for me since for one string ill need the first 4 characters, then another 5 characters to be shortened and will need to be done throughout a workbook.

Any input would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Do you know what these strings are? Is there a limited number of these? If so, you could set up an if that uses 'Left' differently based on what the string is.

Comment: Can you provide samples strings, and the criteria used to change the size

Comment: @KFichter , Yes for the most part they are limited. Each sheet will have say 3 different ones. But these are consistent throughout each workbook

Comment: @paulbica , some strings on sheet 1 would be Beta&3523525 , Then Vega_24r3r3w, Gamma%32422 , so I would shorten these to just the names I want without the numbers. Each seems to only have a few of these each, but they differ from sheet to sheet. So sheet to might have alpha_21414 and so on.

Comment: So you're looking for something that's basically 'Left' but for the first alphabetical characters and get rid of anything after?

Comment: This might help http://superuser.com/questions/951802/how-can-i-parse-a-string-from-a-cell-multiple-time-in-excel/951862?noredirect=1#comment1299645_951862

Comment: @KFichter yes preciesely, alphabetical and numbers usually followed by an '_' or something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found that determining the ASCII character number with the [CODE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CODE-function-C32B692B-2ED0-4A04-BDD9-75640144B928) (using [UPPER function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/UPPER-function-C11F29B3-D1A3-4537-8DF6-04D0049963D6) to reduce the possibilities) produces satisfactory results.

[image: truncate at First non-alphabetic character]

The array formula in B2 for strictly alphabetic characters is,

```
=LEFT(A2, MIN(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2)))+((CODE(MID(UPPER(A2), ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2))), 1))>64)*(CODE(MID(UPPER(A2), ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2))), 1))<91))*1E+99)-1)
```

An array formula in B2 for alphanumeric characters is,

```
=LEFT(A2, MIN(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2)))+(((CODE(MID(UPPER(A2), ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2))), 1))>64)*(CODE(MID(UPPER(A2), ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2))), 1))<91))+((CODE(MID(A2, ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2))), 1))>47)*(CODE(MID(A2, ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2))), 1))<58)))*1E+99)-1)
```

Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>.

A VBA User Defined Function (aka UDF) for strictly alphabetic characters would be,

```
Function just_the_alpha(str As String)
    Dim tmp As String, c As Long
    For c = 1 To Len(str)
        If Asc(Mid(UCase(str), c)) > 64 And _
           Asc(Mid(UCase(str), c)) < 91 Then
            tmp = tmp & Mid(str, c, 1)
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
    Next c
    just_the_alpha = tmp
End Function
```

A VBA UDF for alphanumeric characters would be,

```
Function just_the_alphanum(str As String)
    Dim tmp As String, c As Long
    For c = 1 To Len(str)
        If (Asc(Mid(UCase(str), c)) > 64 And _
            Asc(Mid(UCase(str), c)) < 91) Or _
           (Asc(Mid(str, c)) > 47 And _
            Asc(Mid(str, c)) < 58) Then
            tmp = tmp & Mid(str, c, 1)
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
    Next c
    just_the_alphanum = tmp
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks I got it! can this be made into a macro?

Comment: Pretty much anything that can be done one a worksheet can be done within VBA, even if you have to use VBA's [WorksheetFunction object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834434.aspx) to achieve it. The operative question is whether you want a macro Sub or a User Defined Function (aka UDF). I don't understand the purpose of the former and the latter is redundant if a conventional worksheet formula can accomplish the task.

Comment: Thanks Jeeped!! Also, I am struggling adjusting the formula to get the strings to get what I want perfectly. Ex: if I wannt alpha01_34242 , it will give me alpha only

Comment: My answer was in response to the sample data you left in a comment. If you have diverse conditions and criteria, edit your question to include sample data together with expected results. Include what you have done to accomplish the task (working or not and beyond simply copying my formula from above into your question).

Comment: I had several  words that are either sepearated by a  -, _ , +.  So example one sheet has pv01_52352, pv+50, pv-100, irvega_242422, so the irvega word works. but for the pv's i am struggling with. The desired results are the works before the special characters, so it would be pv01, pv and irvega as a desired result

Comment: Perhaps we have an ESL communication problem. I thought I was quite specific when I typed *"edit your question to include ..."*.

Comment: Thanks , any tips on how to make this a macro for a workbook?

Comment: What do the UDFs you made do? How can I use them? Are they just pasted into a module? Or do you use them as a formula?